# Is there a way to make a batch file to autofill / auto populate a file path into another application which opens via the batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

```
cd /D %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Citrix\AGEE
Start epaPackage.exe
```

[image: Folder Population IMAGE]

I'm trying to automate the process of manually browsing for the file path for a batch files.

The file path is **`"%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Citrix\EPAPack"`**

The image shows the application the batch file opens and the File Path it asks for, or the option to manually navigate to the folder

Comment: Batch files use the CLI, they do not interact with GUI applications, unless you leverage another scripting language which can. Can you not just use the clipboard? e.g. `Echo(%LocalAppData%\Citrix\EPAPack|Clip` then you could just Ctrl+V to paste it into the GUI dialog box.

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have to do this. I was just trying to make it as user friendly as possible as I've got a lot of users who don't know how to use computers too well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBScript to automate the task:

```
<!-- :: Begin Batch
@Echo Off
cd /D %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Citrix\AGEE
Start epaPackage.exe
Cscript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:vbs
Exit /B
-->
<package>
  <job id="vbs">
    <script language="vbscript">
      Wscript.Sleep 2000
      Dim WshShell
      Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
      WshShell.AppActivate("epaPackage")
      Wscript.Sleep 2000
      Set UserProfile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
      Set StrPath = UserProfile & "\\Appdata\\Local\\Citrix\\EPAPack"
      WshShell.SendKeys(StrPath)
      WshShell.SendKeys("{DOWN}")
      WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've just tried this, the same pop up shows up with the field remaining blank the way it was. Is there anything I can add?

Comment: @WasifHasan Maybe need send 1st the **`{TAB}`** key  (1x or 2x) to go the input area... or not!?

Comment: @It wasn't me, yes it is but where to send it?

Comment: @WasifHasan 1st sendkey use send key tab!